# Rewrite host to other host with some complications

Tags: nginx, redirect

I had a site on domiy.com and now I'm changing the name to namedar.com. I'd like to 301 redirect all requests for domiy.com (or nametyper.com) so that they return namedar.com with the request URI intact.

I've tried simply redirecting everything to namedar.com but that leads to a redirect loop when a request arrives for namedar.com.

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://nametyper.com$request_uri permanent; # Doesn't work
```

I'd also like to keep the configuration set up in such a way that all 'www' requests are redirected to the non-www version.

My `nginx.conf` looks like this at the moment:

```
server {
  server_name namedar.com www.namedar.com domiy.com www.domiy.com nametyper.com www.nametyper.com;

  # Remove all 'www.' prefixes.
  if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
    set $host_without_www $1;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

How do I write a `rewrite` directive in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me split your concerns to two steps...

Step 1: www to non-www

```
server {
  server_name www.domainname.com;
  return 301 $scheme://domainname.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name domainname.com;
  # [...] regular blocks and directives
}
```

Step 2: first_domain.com to second_domain.com

```
server {
  server_name first_domain.com www.first_domain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://second_domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

You may modify the above steps to make it work for any number of domains. Also, you can combine both to happen in a single step.

BTW, in Nginx, [if is considered as evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Comment: Is it possible to share configuration settings between server blocks? I have a load of other config settings which I left out of my question for clarities sake. This would all have to be duplicated if I go with your solution.

Comment: @duckyfuzz From what I know, it is not possible to share configuration settings between server blocks. I wish I'm wrong here.

Comment: Actually, it tuns out that I don't need to share configuration. I just left all the configuration in the 'namedar.com' server block added another small server block which simply redirects everything to that. Seems to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: @duckyfuzz Glad to know, it worked for you.